# Symfony doesn't take my Length Assert in account

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm writing validations on Symfony for a User Entity which has a password attribute.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

...

class User implements UserInterface {
    
    ...
    
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    private $password;

    /**
    * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Veuillez indiquer un mot de passe")
    * @Assert\Length(
    *   min=8,
    *   max=4096,
    *   minMessage="Votre mot de passe doit contenir au moins {{limit}} cacactères",
    *   maxMessage="Votre mot de passe ne doit pas contenir plus de {{limit}} caractères"
    * )
    */
    private $plain_password;
    
    ...
    
}
```

As you can see, I prevent the password from being empty and I check that its length is greater or equal to 8 characters.

But in addition, in the signup form I added a password confirmation thanks to the "Repeated" type provided by Symfony.

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\UrlType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class UserFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('plain_password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_name' => 'first',
                'second_name' => 'confirmation',
                'invalid_message' => 'La confirmation ne correspond pas avec le mot de passe'
            ])
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('website', UrlType::class)
            ->add('facebook')
            ->add('twitter')
            ->add('instagram')
            ->add('avatar')
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, when I submit the form leaving the password field blank, I get the proper message *"Veuillez indiquer un mot de passe"*.

When I submit the form with different values in the two password fields, I get also the proper message *"La confirmation ne correspond pas avec le mot de passe"*.

But, when I submit the form with equal and not blank values in the two password fields, but with a length lower than 8; I do not get* any error message and the user is peacefully saved.

---

#### EDIT:

Alsatian: I don't have validation group set for the form

Controller action:

```
public function signupAction(Request $request) {
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserFormType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    return $this->render('user/signup.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Seems similar to this open bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14589

Comment: Don't you have a validation group set for the form ? Is the form binded with your user entity ? Can you show the full form class please ? And eventually the controller. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if you need to add a Validated annotation at the top of User.  You've added validation constraint to Form and Entity both. The one in the Form is being respected, but the one(s) in the entity are not.